# How to pass values or reference objects between the sceen powerapps

Tags: windows, powerapps

I am developing an app using PowerApps Web. Tried to integrate excel file which has tables in it. There is table called "employee" which has few details about employee. In first screen i just show employee listing with names in it. But when user clicks on any of the listing item, i would want to show the details about the employee in the next screen.

Note: I am able to connect to the excel file which is in dropbox. Excel file has employee table information. But only the problem is passing reference of selected employee to the next screen in powerapps.

Thanks! 
Bhat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the [`Navigate` call](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/function-navigate/) that you use to move from a screen to the next you can pass an optional third parameter (context) that is passed to the next screen.

So for example, if you display your employee names in a gallery in the first screen, and within one of the controls of the gallery you handle the OnSelect action to navigate to the next screen, you can pass the ThisItem value that represents the value that is being used in the gallery:

```
Navigate(ScreenDetails, ScreenTransition.Fade, { employee: ThisItem })
```

In the second screen (ScreenDetails), you can access the properties of the selected employee by using the `employee` context variable. For example, if you have a text box (label) in that screen, you can set its Text property to

```
employee.FullName
```

And that will show the name of the employee that you selected in the previous screen.

Comment: Thanks carlosfigueira